# where is fyne's thread safety defined?

Tags: go, thread-safety, fyne

I was attracted to Fyne (and hence Go) by a promise of thread safety. But now that I'm getting better at reading Go I'm seeing things that make be believe that the API as a whole is not thread safe and perhaps was never intended to be. So I'm trying to determine what "thread safe" means in Fyne.

I'm looking specifically at

```
func (l *Label) SetText(text string) {
    l.Text = text
    l.textProvider.SetText(text) // calls refresh
}
```

and noting that l.Text is also a string. Assignments in Go are not thread safe, so it seems obvious to me that if two threads fight over the text of a label and both call label.SetText at the same time, I can expect memory corruption.

"But you wouldn't do that", one might say. No, but I am worried about the case of someone editing the content of an Entry while an app thread decides it needs to replace all the Entry's text - this is entirely possible in my app because it supports simultaneous editing by multiple users over a network, so updates to all sorts of widgets come in asynchronously. (Note I don't care what happens if two people edit the same Entry at the same time; someone's changes will be lost and I don't care who's. But it must not result in memory corruption.) Note that one approach I could take would be to have the background thread create an entirely new Entry widget, which would then replace the one in the current Box. But is that thread safe?

It's not that I don't know how to serialize things with channels. But I was hoping that Fyne would eliminate the need for it (a blog post claims it does); and even using channels I can't convince myself that a user meddling with a widget in various ways while some background thread is altering it, hiding it, etc, isn't going to result in crashes. Maybe all that is serialized under the covers and is perfectly safe, but I don't want to find out the hard way that it isn't, because I'll have no way to fix it.

Fyne is clearly pretty new and seems to have tons of promise, but documentation seems light on details. Is more information available somewhere? Have people tried this successfully?

Comment: Not familiar with `fyne` - but if you are correct: if two go-routines - get out of the habit of calling them threads in go - if two go-routines call `Label.SetText(...)` there will be a data-race. However I assume there would be just one UI go-routine handling UI updates - so that would avoid any contention.

Comment: According to [the bug tracker](https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne/issues/506) there are several known data races. They are considered bugs, apparently, so not intentional behavior.

Comment: Yes @colminator the UI updates are painted on a single thread but the API is designed to accept changes from any goroutine. It is not yet 100% thread safe but it should be in the future.

Comment: Documentation is currently in many places and the website should be updated soon to fix this. https://fyne.io/develop/ and https://tour.fyne.io/ are the main places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have found some race conditions here. There are plans to improve, but the 1.2 release was required to get a new "BaseWidget" first - and that was only released a few weeks ago.

1. Setting fields directly is primarily for setup purposes and so not expected to be used in the way you illustrate. That said, we do want to support it. The base widget will soon introduce something akin to `SetFieldsAndRefresh(func())` which will ensure the safety of the code passed and refresh the widget afterward.
2. There is indeed a race currently within `Refresh()`. The use of channels internally were designed to remove this - but there are some corners such as multiple goroutines calling it. This is the area that our new BaseWidget code can help with - as they can internally lock automatically. Using this approach will be thread safe with no changes to the developer in a future release.

The API so far has made it possible for developers to not worry about threading and work from any goroutines - we do need to work internally to make it safer - you are quite right. https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne/issues/506